# NancyFx Queries to JSON files stripping the JSON extension from request URL

Tags: nancy, self-hosting

In one project I'm using Nancy to serve basic web content via Nancy Self-Host. This generally works, but unfortunately, running queries on endpoints ie `http://localhost/data.json` results in the module receiving a request url of `http://localhost/data`.

When I query `localhost/data.json` I get a nancy-generated 404 response... in JSON. I have no clue why this is happening, and can't find this behavior documented anywhere.

Here's my module:

```
public class NancySimpleWebModule : NancyModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// TODO - HACK!
    /// </summary>
    public static NancySimpleWebServer WebServer;

    public NancySimpleWebModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = Get[@"/{url*}"] = _ =>
        {
            string filePath = WebServer.ResolveFilePath(Request.Url.Path.Trim('/', '\\'));
            if (filePath == null || filePath.Length == 0 || !File.Exists(filePath))
                return new Response { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound };

            return File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        };
    }
}
```

Here's how I start the server:

```
        _host = new NancyHost(
            new HostConfiguration { UrlReservations = new UrlReservations { CreateAutomatically = true } },
            uriToBind);

        _host.Start();
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you do a request to `/data.json` the `url` parameter inside your route definition has the value `data`, right? Then the `404` happens because there is no file called `data` (without `.json`) in which case the code explicitly returns `404`.

Comment: The issue isn't the 404, the issue is that .json is being stripped from the URL

I ended up modifying Nancy source where it was stripping extensions from request URLs for known data format extensions

Comment: Yeah, that's part of Nancys content negotiation. The idea is that the extension can used to indication how the clients wants the data returned. E.g. `data.json` to get back json or `data.xml` to get back xml. So if the route handler returns an object the framework serializes it based on the extension.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [#1919](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1919), [#2671](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2671) and [#2711](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2711) this is by design and you're unable to disable it:

> This is a feature of [content negotiation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Content-Negotiation#file-extension-support).

This happens for both `.xml` and `.json`.

Suggested workarounds would be to add something after the extension (`GET /foo/bar.json/baz`) or to rename the files (`/foo/bar.js`).

Answer (score 0):

You can override config, using this bootstrapper code:

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override NancyInternalConfiguration InternalConfiguration
    {
        get
        {
            return NancyInternalConfiguration.WithOverrides(x =>
            {
                // Otherwise '.xml' and '.json' will get stripped off request paths
                x.ResponseProcessors = new List<Type>
                {
                    typeof(ResponseProcessor),
                    typeof(ViewProcessor)
                };
            });
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2671#issuecomment-349088969