# Nancy does not support periods in URL

Tags: c#, nancy

Here is my path defined in a module constructor:

```
Get["/{company_id}/storage/{fileName}"] = x => { return ReadFileFromStorage(x.company_id, x.fileName); };
```

Here is the URL passed in:

```
http://localhost/MOCK/storage/foo.xml
```

x.fileName is set to "foo" and only "foo". No ".xml" is shown.
I see the following results:

```
this.Request.Path = "/MOCK/storage/foo"
this.Request.Url = "http://localhost/MOCK/storage/foo"
```

Escaping also yields the result above: `http://localhost/MOCK/storage/foo%2Exml`

Note that in the Add pipelinethe data is just fine, with the .xml showing up fine.

Comment: Please don't answer your question in the question itself. Instead, post an actual answer with the workaround. Also, no support for dots in URLs? I'd ditch that library

Comment: `fileName.Contains("")` will always return true, so I don't see the point of the conditional.

Comment: Ok I remove the workaround, because this is NOT what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does your code exhibit this issue for all extensions, or just `.xml`?

Comment: I suspect what is happening is your Content Negotiation is intercepting the request, and determining that you are requesting an XML response.

Comment: [Search this wiki on Content Negotiation for "File extension support"](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Content-Negotiation)

Comment: Aha!  @Amy I think you're 100% on the right track - thank you!

Comment: Feel free to submit that as an answer to your question.  I don't use Nancy, I just had a hunch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NancyFx Queries stripping the JSON extension from request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462517/).

Answer (score 0):

Per @Amy, yes indeed, this is by design, part of content negotiation, as answered here for the .json extension: [NancyFx Queries to JSON files stripping the JSON extension from request URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462517/nancyfx-queries-to-json-files-stripping-the-json-extension-from-request-url)